# Titled Seperator in Intellij Plugin Configurable

Tags: java, swing, intellij-plugin

I am trying to create a seperator with a title. Here is an example (from the Intellij Idea Scala plugin):

[image]

I tried both a JSeparator and a titled border, but both aren't what you can see in the picture: The JSeparator doesn't support text titles, and the titled border surrounds the entire panel, and isn't just on top.

Any idea how such separator can be created? Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`TitledSeparator`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-api/src/com/intellij/ui/TitledSeparator.java) class.

To discover any of the existing UI implementations, you can use [UI Inspector](https://jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/internal_actions/internal_ui_inspector.html).